# Push parallelization stop randomly on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, parallel-processing, push-notification, threadpool

I want to send a push campaign to all my users (around 500k), but the heroku dyno stop randomly during the execution (I'm using a one-off dyno and no exceptions are raised).
I am using the gem [Parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) :

```
User.where(some_stuff).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |group|
  Parallel.each(group, in_threads: 8) do |u|
    u.push('hi') # pushing the message via GCM or APN
  end
end
```

In all the cases I tested, the process stops at the end of a batch, but I can't find a pattern when playing with `batch_size` and `in_threads` values.

The `push` function doesn't need a database access, but maybe that the `find_in_batch` function get rejected because of too many connections?

I use a [performance-l](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types) dyno with 14GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When activating the [Heroku log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), I can see that the `memory_pgpin` and `memory_pgpout` varies significantly during the execution :

memory_pgpin : *19 240* to *73 998*

memory_pgpout : *222* to *12 784*

I suppose it is a problem with my postgres plan, but if you have further explanation, don't hesitate to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do long running operations in your application server processes. The application server attaches a thread/process to the incoming request and will wipe out any thread that you will spawn at the end of the request processing. you should do long running operations in the background. have a look at sidekik or resque.

Comment: I'm using a one-off dyno, not a web dyno.